How to snap during rotation?
I'm trying to complete a tutorial, but have accidentally created something in the wrong orientation. As the aforelinked depicts, I'm creating a structure which necessitates exact alignment. However, when I rotate, the snapping toolbar button is not active - I am able to rotate to any degree of precision that I desire.
How can I force the rotation tool to snap?

The "Precision" section of the transformation documentation provides the answer:

Holding Ctrl during a transform operation (such as move, rotate or scale) will toggle Transform Snapping. When using Increment Snap, this allows the transformation to be performed in discrete amounts.

